# Dimension of vector space over $F_2$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Good morning,

Let $F_2=\{0,1\}$ be finite field,and $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\
         0
       \end{bmatrix}$ over $F_2$.

and let $V= \langle \begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\
         0
       \end{bmatrix}\rangle$, where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ mean span, so what are the vectors in $V$ over $F$ and the dimension of vector space $V$.

thanks.

Comment: Span means the same over $\Bbb F_2$ as it does over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. Try applying that, and you should get the right answer.

Comment: There's a single non-zero generator, so the dimension is $1$, by definition. To have all vectors in $V$, you multiply this generator by all possible values in $\mathbf F_2$ – which aren't that many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and $\dim V=1$.